# Error in downloading MODIS image using R script

Tags: r, remote-sensing, modis, satellite, digital-image-processing

I am trying to download "MOD13A3" MODIS image using R script (http://r-gis.net/?q=ModisDownload) but each time it's ending in error. How to make it work ?

```
=================================================================================
setwd("D:/MODIS_Download_R")  
source('ModisDownload.R')  
library(raster)  
library(RCurl)  
modisProducts()  
x="MOD13A3"  
ModisDownload(x=x,h=c(25,26),v=c(06,06),dates=c('2013.01.01','2013.12.31'))

==================================================================================

Error in .modisHTTP(x, v = version) :
the http address does not exist! Version may be incorrect OR Server is down!

==================================================================================
```

I have kept ***ModisDownload.R***, ***ModisLP*** and ***Rcurl*** in the same working directory.

Comment: The script as downloaded from r-gis works fine for me, with the parameters that you have provided. The LPDAAC servers, where the data is downloaded from, are at times a big sluggish, and a connection loss may lead to errors not accounted for in the script - this is pure guessing, as the script is functional for me and the error message that you indicate is not something that I have seen happen.

Comment: Am I missing any library, or some other required R packages here ? I can only see the list of MODIS products, after that its end up into error. I have been doing this since last 2 days, so server problem is unlikely to happen. There is something wrong with the code or my approach.

Comment: Libraries required are: raster, sp, bitops & RCurl all of which should be installed and loaded in the usual R way.

Comment: > library(sp)
> library(bitops)
> library(raster)
> library(RCurl)
> library(rgdal)
> setwd('D:/MODIS_Download_R')
> source('ModisDownload.R')
> modisProducts()

Do you find any mistake here ?

Comment: None, assuming that you have the 'ModisDownload.R' and 'ModisLP.RData' in the 'D:/MODIS_Download_R'-folder.

Comment: Yeah.. I have'ModisDownload.R' and 'ModisLP' (not 'ModisLP.RData') in the 'D:/MODIS_Download_R'-folder.

Comment: The reason you see it as 'ModisLP' and not 'ModisLP.RData' is because your windows hides extensions of known formats. If all of the above runs without problems, then I can't help you as I can't replicate the error.

Comment: Is anything wrong with the R version (I am using 3.2.0) or the firewall ?

Comment: @dSb The script from r-gis and your procedure works fine for me too (in Linux).

Comment: @dSb It works fine for me too in Windows 7 with, precisely, 3.2.0 R version. What Windows version do you have?

Comment: @xunilk I tried this in Window 7 64-bit and Window XP 32-bit system with R 3.2 and it ended up in same error. I don't know what is wrong with me ?

Comment: Success with Windows XP too. By the way, this is strange: "I have kept ... and Rcurl in the same working directory". RCurl is a library. It must be installed with "install.packages()"; in Windows Seven as Administrator.

Comment: I have installed RCurl with "install.packages()" in window. I don't know what is wrong here, it's working for everyone except me.

Comment: Finally I could do it in Ubuntu 14.04 after failing in Window XP and Window 7 @xunilk I have used R 3.0.2 in Ubuntu

Comment: I could not download images with R because the USGS server is using http and ftp ModisDownload.R is, can you help me ??

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/95864)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/95864)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check whether you can access FTP files from your institute server or not?
I also faced similar problem, and found it was because of restriction in FTP accessing.

Comment: Yes, I too had this problem because of ftp restriction.  I could resolve it after requesting the IT staff.

Answer (score 1):

Try the most recent `ModisDownload()` function from the `rts` package. Its last version allows for the needed NASA authentication prior to search and download. It also allows you to mosaic and to reproject the raw `.hdr` files downloaded (for the latter, you need to install the Modis Download Tool from NASA - [link](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/tools/modis_reprojection_tool)) to generate, say, a geotiff of all your tiles together. Try

```
devtools::install_github('babaknaimi/rts')  # must install the latest one
library(rts)

setNASAauth("yourNASAlogin", "yourNASApassword", update = T) # authenticates at NASA's server
> username and password are successfully updated...!
```

Then to download the required images:

```
ModisDownload(x='MOD13A3',h=c(25,26),v=c(06,06),dates=c('2013.01.01','2013.12.31'), mosaic=F, proj=F)
```